# What does Integer.parseInt do?

Tags: java

I am just now starting to learn Java and one of my tasks is to go through this piece of code and understand what it does. However I am having trouble doing that, despite having consulted many online sources. In particular, I am still struggling to understand the declaration of the variables stake, goal and num_trials. What does Integer.parseInt(args[0]) mean? Please explain in very simple words as I am very new to OOP.

```
public class GamblerRuin{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int goal = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int num_trials = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        int bets = 0;
        int wins = 0;

        for (int t = 0; t < num_trials; t++)
        {
            int cash = stake;
            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal)
            {
                bets++;
                if (Math.random() < 0.5 ) cash++;
                else                      cash--;
            }
            if (cash == goal) wins++;
        }

        System.out.println(100 * wins/num_trials + "% wins");
        System.out.println("Avg # bets: " + bets/num_trials);

    }
}
```

Comment: From what you've read online, what did you gather? And how will you go about understanding such things in future? (asking a question one concept at a time is an impractical method when the number of things to learn is quasi-infinite)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your program with arguments like this:

```
javac GambleRuin 1 2 3
```

Then your program will be executed by calling the main function.

The `String[] args` array will be `["1","2","3"]`. Since the arguments always pass as strings, you need to cast them to integers for your program to work, hence parse int

Warning: if the arguments are not integers, then an exception will be thrown and your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

> Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

means the following:

1. `args` is a `String` array and you access the first item in that array
   which is a `String`
2. `Integer.parseInt` takes a `String` and converts it to an `int`. 
   For example: `Integer.parseInt("21");` returns `21`.